# GitHub Action: Provide webhook callback URL custom and wait for completion

Tags: github, action, webhooks, github-webhook

I am looking for a method to generate a custom webhook callback URL unique to each build within my github action. The purpose of this is that I have a github action which simply starts a test on a server (i.e. browserstack)and returns. It has the option to provide a webhook to call upon test completion.

I ideally would want to somehow generate a webhook custom to this build, and then trigger another action which waits for the webhook callback before continuing. I can always have a polling mechanism which runs every 60 seconds, but I personally prefer to avoid this.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Personally, I don't think this is possible unless you implement polling but then you're using your build minutes and concurrent jobs limits. Ideally, I wish there would be an option for a job to wait for a webhook call before executing. This would allow a lot more integrations.